# Class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found Laravel Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, pusher

I am testing pusher in my laravel lumen but i get an error with Pusher\Pusher:
[image: Pusher Error]

I have already tried adding an alias for it and registering it but still no luck:

```
$app->alias('Pusher', Pusher\Pusher::class);
$app->register(Pusher\Pusher::class);
```

i have also deleted my vendor folder and reintalled my composer dependencies.

see below for my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "appzcoder/lumen-routes-list": "^1.1",
        "dusterio/lumen-passport": "^0.2.15",
        "google/cloud-text-to-speech": "^0.5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "illuminate/mail": "6.0",
        "illuminate/redis": "^6.2",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^6.0",
        "laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish": "6.0",
        "league/flysystem": "^1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~2.0",
        "smalot/pdfparser": "^0.14.0",
        "superbalist/flysystem-google-storage": "^7.2",
        "superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage": "^2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `pusher/pusher-php-server` sdk package version `3` or later. Pusher PHP sdk use namespace from version `3`. To learn more visit their GitHub [repo](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/releases/tag/3.0.0)